# Pattern matching in if statement in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to count the words with at least two vowels in all the .txt files in the directory. Here's my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

wordcount=0


for i in $HOME/*.txt
do
cat $i |
while read line
do
    for w in $line
    do
    if [[ $w == .*[aeiouAEIOU].*[AEIOUaeiou].* ]]
    then
        wordcount=`expr $wordcount + 1`
        echo $w ':' $wordcount  
    else
        echo "In else"
    fi
    done
done
echo $i ':' $wordcount
wordcount=0
done
```

Here is my sample from a txt file

> Last modified: Sun Aug 20 18:18:27 IST 2017 
>   To remove PPAs 
>   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
>   sudo ppa-purge ppa:

The problem is it doesn't match the pattern in the if statement for all the words in the text file. It goes directly to the else statement. And secondly, the wordcount in echo $i ':' $wordcount is equal to 0 which should be some value.

Comment: Replace `cat $i | while ...; do ...; done` by `while ...; do ...; done <<< "$i"`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Wanmi If your problem is a regex, why is the code in this question more than two lines -- one to assign a fixed string to a variable, a second one to apply a regex to that variable's contents? There's surely much more code here than the minimum needed to demonstrate your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using grep - this is pretty simple to do.

```
#!/bin/bash

wordcount=0
for file in ./*.txt
do
count=`cat $file | xargs -n1 | grep -ie "[aeiou].*[aeiou]" | wc -l`
wordcount=`expr $wordcount + $count`
done

echo $wordcount
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Immediate Issue: Glob vs Regex

`[[ $string = $pattern ]]` doesn't perform regex matching; instead, it's a glob-style pattern match. While `.` means "any character" in regex, it matches only itself in glob.

You have a few options here:

1. Use `=~` instead to perform regular expression matching:

   ```
   [[ $w =~ .*[aeiouAEIOU].*[AEIOUaeiou].* ]]
   ```
2. Use a glob-style expression instead of a regex:

   ```
   [[ $w = *[aeiouAEIOU]*[aeiouAEIOU]* ]]
   ```

   <sub>Note the use of `=` rather than `==` here; while either is technically valid, the former avoids building finger memory that would lead to bugs when writing code for a POSIX implementation of `test` / `[`, as `=` [is the only valid string comparison operator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) there.</sub>

---

#### Larger Issue: Properly Reading Word-By-Word

Using `for w in $line` is innately unsafe. Use `read -a` to read a line into an array of words:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wordcount=0
for i in "$HOME"/*.txt; do
  while read -r -a words; do
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do
      if [[ $word = *[aeiouAEIOU]*[aeiouAEIOU]* ]]; then
        (( ++wordcount ))
      fi
    done
  done <"$i"
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$i" "$wordcount"
  wordcount=0
done
```

Comment: Thanks this is a comprehensive answer. I was frustrated using bash until i realised the patterns glob!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '/[aeiouAEIOU].*[AEIOUaeiou]/{n++} ENDFILE{print FILENAME":"n; n=0}' RS='[[:space:]]' *.txt
```

Sample output looks like:

```
$ awk '/[aeiouAEIOU].*[AEIOUaeiou]/{n++} ENDFILE{print FILENAME":"n; n=0}' RS='[[:space:]]' *.txt
one.txt:1
sample.txt:9
```

How it works:

- `/[aeiouAEIOU].*[AEIOUaeiou]/{n++}`

  Every time we find a word with two vowels, we increment variable `n`.
- `ENDFILE{print FILENAME":"n; n=0}`

  At the end of each file, we print the name of the file and the 2-vowel word count `n`.  We then reset `n` to zero.
- `RS='[[:space:]]'`

  This tells awk to use any whitespace as a word separator.   This makes each word into a *record*.  Awk reads the input one record at a time.

#### Shell issues

The use of awk avoids a multitude of shell issues.  For example, consider the line `for w in $line`.  This will not work the way you hope.  Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
one.txt  sample.txt
```

Now, let's take `line='* Item One'` and see what happens:

```
$ line='* Item One'
$ for w in $line; do echo "w=$w"; done
w=one.txt
w=sample.txt
w=Item
w=One
```

The shell treats the `*` in `line` as a wildcard and expands it into a list of files.  Odds are you didn't want this.  The awk solution avoids a variety of issues like this.

Comment: The "shell issues" you refer to are specific to `for w in $line`. They don't happen when following [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) practices (and, particularly, the guidance [not to iterate over lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)), and more generally avoiding unquoted expansion.

Comment: (Which is to say -- it would be unfair for me to describe a common awk mistake -- say, failing to put initialization code in a BEGIN block -- as a reason not to use the language; I'd argue that the same is true with common shell bugs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, of course, as you well know, it is possible to do shell right.  The OP's shell code, does have multiple issues and I was just illustrating the consequences of one of them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see that the your updated answer addresses all the other issues with the OP's shell code.  +1.